# Access variables in @Remoteaction

Tags: apex, remote-action

I have a `@RemoteAction` function in my `Apex Class`. I have a public static variable in this class. When I access this variable in the `@RemoteMethod`, there is error saying variable doesn't exist. When I make the class, method, and variable all `global`, the code compiles, but the variable is still `null`.

Can anyone help me in what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that your `RemoteAction` is `static`. If the `static` variable you are trying to reference is set by `instance` logic in your controller, the new transaction context of the `RemoteAction` will lose that stateful information.

**Works:**

```
static Object myProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (myProperty == null)
        {
            // instantiate
        }
        return myProperty;
    }
    private set;
}
```

**Doesn't Work:**

```
static Object myProperty;
public MyController()
{
    myProperty = somethingStateful;
}
```

If `myProperty` depends on stateful information, it's not really `static` after all, **even if you declare it so**. Any state you want to maintain in your `RemoteAction` must be passed through parameters.

Answer (score 7):

Remote action runs in another context so you don't have access to controller variables (think of it like a `@future` method). You can pass some Ids or something similar to your remote action and then query it from your Database if you need. Also serialization might work if you want to pass an object.